# Export SCSS to CSS into a JS file, automatically

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

Due to the constraints in the work I'm doing the output has to be a single **.js** file. In it, we sometimes have to use styling. Right now, we're appending the style by a string:

```
var style = 'body{ background:#000; }';
$('<style>' + style + '</style>').appendTo('head');
```

In an **.scss** file it is also possible to automatically export and save as a single string **.css** file, which I have working through the SASS Live Compiler-plugin.

Now I would love to combine these 2.

**Is it possible to automatically (minify and) export a single CSS string from an .scss file into a .js file to a designated spot?**

Comment: You would have to incorporate [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)  into your project. It takes a single `.js` entry point and uses different loaders to inject css/html etc... into the `bundle.js`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Another way to go would be to use [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/), which is a CSS-in-JS technique.